# Throw exception with a contextual UnityEngine.Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, we can use `Debug.LogError` (and other log methods) to define a `context` parameter along with the message. For example:

```cs
Debug.LogError("I am an error", aContext);
```

The code above will print an error to the Unity Console and then we can click the error to highlight the object passed as `context` in the Hierarchy window. (By "object" I always mean `UnityEngine.Object` and derivatives). The method `Debug.LogError` does not raise an exception nor it stop the execution of the method, it prints the error silently.

Also in Unity, we can throw a `System.Exception` like any other C# program. Even it is not a "Unity thing" (it is from C#), it gets caught in the Unity console. We can do that simply by calling `throw new System.Exception("My message here")`.

Question: There is some way to **throw** some type of Exception with a context similar to the `Debug.LogError`, so when I click the console it highlights an `UnityEngine.Object` passed as parameter? I do not want to call both `Debug.LogError` and `throw` because it would be duplicated in the Unity console (this is the only thing I complain about).

What I expect is to call `throw new SomeSpecialOrMadeException("My message here", aContext);`, so it behaves like a C# exception, but it highlights the object in the Hierarchy window when I click the error in the console at same time.